Integral inequality proof
Problem: Let f(x) be a convex function and integrable on [a, b]. Prove that
$$ \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^b f(x)dx \le \frac{f(a) + f(b)}{2} $$
Here my try: Since f(x) is a convex function so  it is continuous on [a,b].
According to the IVM theorem for definite integral, $\exists$c = $\frac{a+b}{2}$ $\in$ [a,b] such that: $$  \int_{a}^b f(x)dx = f(c)(b-a)= f(\frac{a+b}{2})(b-a) $$ $$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^b f(x)dx = f(\frac{a+b}{2}) (*)$$ Meanwhile, f(x) is a convex function so according to the convex function inequality, $$f(\frac{a+b}{2}) = f(\frac{1}{2}a + (1-\frac{1}{2})b) \le \frac{1}{2}f(a)+ (1-\frac{1}{2})f(b) = \frac{f(a) + f(b)}{2} (**) $$ From (*) and (**) $\Rightarrow$ Q.E.D
However, I think that I cannot choose $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$ as c is just a random value inside [a,b], but I cannot find any other ways to prove. Please help me

Minor quib: $f$ is convex on $[a, b]$ implies continuity on $(a, b)$. You cannot infer continuity at the endpoints. Take, for example, the indicator function of the set ${0, 1}$ as a function $[0, 1]\to\mathbb{R}$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{b - a}\int_a^b f(x)~dx &= \int_0^1 f\left(a + (b - a)t\right)~dt\\
&= \int_0^1 f\left((1 - t)a + tb\right)~dt\\
&\leqslant \int_0^1 (1 - t)f(a) + tf(b)~dt = \frac{f(a) + f(b)}{2}.
\end{align*}
